# External SSD drive can only be detected when Android is on 100% battery

Tags: battery, usb-on-the-go, usb-storage

Android 11 will communicate with the external drive using a -y- connector, one lead to power, and the other lead to PNY 1TB drive.

However, once the battery drains below 100 percent, Android refuses to acknowledge the connection to an external drive unless the drive has been connected at one hundred percent battery charge. Unplug the external drive while the battery is below one hundred percent charge and you are forced to wait until the battery is charged to one hundred percent before you can reconnect to the aforementioned drive.

That being said, I am able to connect -y- cable to Android and to the external drive as long as the battery is charged to one hundred percent, establish a connection to the drive and then unplug the power lead and remain connected to the drive until the battery is drained.

How about addressing this limitation?

Comment: USB y cables that you describe are not covered by the USB standard. That means they can work or not, in your case it seems to be the latter. Better try a USB-C hub with upstream power delivery (assuming your phone has an USB-C connector and supports power delivery). BTW: I don't understand the title of your question.

Comment: @Robert I've updated the title since the original didn't describe the issue.